# how to determine range of commits needed to run an incremental build with NX

Tags: git, continuous-integration, nrwl, nrwl-nx

In a CI/CD server, how can I determine the range of commits to include in the `nx affected:build --base=master~1 --head=master` command?

https://nx.dev/react/api/workspace/npmscripts/affected-build

```
nx affected

Run task for affected projects

Run command using --base=[SHA1] --head=[SHA2] (affected by the committed changes):
  --base  Base of the current branch (usually master)                   [string]
  --head  Latest commit of the current branch (usually HEAD)            [string]
```

For example, it would be trivial for the use case where only 1 commit to master triggers a build.  But if it were 2 or more commits that triggers a build on CI/CD, then how I can determine the last commit that the build ran on in order to determine some range of commits for the `--head` arg to use?

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer but I guess the best would be to trigger the CI on every commit and then continue only if there where any affecting changes.

This would also reduce the time build, test and deploy will take because they only do smaller chunks of the changes.

But I also guess you already found a working solution.

Comment: that approach will not really work for us.  thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: Do you know the commits and are your CI runs associated to those commits? If so you could do the following. Get your current commits and find the most recent. Than look for the latest successful CI run and extract the associated git commit sha. After that you could simple work with `nx affected --base [sha-base] --head [sha-head]` Hope that makes sense!?

Comment: Yeah, something like that is what I need to look into.  Specifically, we're using teamcity so need to just figure out the specifics of teamcity that will allow me to do that.  I was hoping NX had some magical script to do this, but I think the solution varies with each CI/CD tool.

Comment: Apparently not that I'm aware of. We went with this solution in the end which is now working fairly well. But we also have only one commit per CI run so it is much easier and we only need to look for the last successful run to calculate the diff.
We are running lints and test on every commit and build and deploys are tagged and triggered by those tags. So affected works out of the box for lint and test works but the builds and deploys need the lookup functionality.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you use feature branches for development?  And if so, don't you have merges/PRs to master that contain multiple commits?  But it kinda sounds like you might have configured the CI/CD tool to still run on individual commits some how?

Comment: Yes we are using feature branches. If the feature is ready we create a merge request into the master branch. The MR triggers the CI for linting and testing. The MR is associated with the latest commit in the feature branch so we can use the MR commit sha and the master to let nx calculate the affected stuff. As a site note we are using GitLab and GitLab CI.
But yeah we are using one commit per CI run. This is just how GitLab works. But I guess with git commands you can find the latest from the n commits in your CI Pipeline/Job?